# How do I re-write this MS Access expression for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am new to the site and I have a question regarding some code I have in Access form that I am redoing in SQL Server 2008 and it has SUM, IIF, and IsNumeric all in one line and I am confused as to how to rewrite this in SQL.

```
Sum([Employee COUNT]*IIf(IsNull([2011]),0,CDbl([2011]))*IIf(IsNumeric([Length]),CDbl([Length]),0)) AS Cost
```

Comment: There has to be more than that, because that is Access SQL. What do you mean by SQL?

Comment: Oh I am sorry I meant to SQL Server

Comment: You might like to correct your question and tags.

Comment: Update your question to something like "How do I re-write this MS Access expression for SQL Server", and add the [sql server] tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this will do what you need:

```
Sum([Employee COUNT]
    * (case 
            when [2011] Is Null 
            then 0 
            else cast([2011] as float) 
        end)
    * (case 
            when IsNumeric([Length])= 1 
            then cast([Length] as float) 
            else 0 
        end)) AS Cost
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SUM([Employee Count] 
  * COALESCE(
      [2011],
       CASE WHEN 
         ISNUMERIC([2011]) = 1 
       THEN 
         CAST([2011] AS DECIMAL(18,4) 
       ELSE 
         0 
       END
    )
  * CASE WHEN 
      ISNUMERIC([Length]) = 1
    THEN 
      -- choose your own precision here.
      CAST ([Length] AS DECIMAL(18,4))
    ELSE
      0
    END
) AS Cost
```